# Implement some form of enums in a protocol

Tags: swift, enums

I'm adding Coordinators to my application, where I used to use Navigators. I wrote a basic coordinator protocol, that looks like this.

```
public protocol Coordinator: class {
    /// The array containing any child Coordinators
    var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] { get set }

    func start()
    func show()
}

public extension Coordinator {

    /// Add a child coordinator to the parent
    public func addChildCoordinator(_ childCoordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.childCoordinators.append(childCoordinator)
    }

    /// Remove a child coordinator from the parent
    public func removeChildCoordinator(_ childCoordinator: Coordinator) {
        self.childCoordinators = self.childCoordinators.filter { $0 !== childCoordinator }
    }

}
```

Now, the thing I liked about my implementation of navigators, was that by using an enum, I could navigate to a view. For example, I could do this:

```
navigator.navigate(to: .preferences)
```

Is there a way, I could incorporate this in my coordinator? I know I can't add an enum to the protocol that classes implementing the protocol could change. Also, as you can see I already added a `show()` function to the protocol. Is there a way I could add an enum or typealias or something as a parameter to that function?

Comment: What's the problem to use `func show(parameter: MyEnum)` ?

Comment: Then the cases of `MyEnum` can't be defined in the class implementing the protocol.

Comment: obviously, you can define it outside of protocol

Comment: Off-topic `childCoordinators` should not be part of the protocol, this should be left as an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol Coordinator: class {

    func show(param: MyEnum)
}

enum MyEnum {
case first
}
```

Imho, it's enough

Comment: This still has the problem I just told you about. Let's say I have class `AppCoordinator` and class `PreferencesCoordinator`. How do they both provide their own cases for `MyEnum`?